# How do I get generate an IP address range given start and end IP address?

Tags: java

How can generate a range of IP addresses from a start and end IP address?

Example for a network "192.168.0.0/24":

```
String start = "192.168.0.2"
String end = "192.168.0.254"
```

I want to have:

```
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
192.168.0.4
192.168.0.5
...
192.168.0.254
```

PS: Network, start and end IP can be dynamic above is just an example.

Thanks...

Comment: You have to know the subnet in order to do that.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I just added the information.

Comment: How do you want the resulting addresses? Do you just want to print them out, or do you want to store them in some sort of data structure?

Comment: @jswolf19: I want them as strings which later I will be persisting to the database.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Recognize that each of the 4 components of an IPv4 address is really a hex number between 00 and FF.

If you change your start and end IP addresses into 32 bit unsigned integers, you can just loop from the lowest one to the highest one and convert each value you loop through back into the IP address format.

The range in the example you give is C0A80002 to C0A800FE.

Here's a link to code that converts between a hex number and an IPv4 address

http://technojeeves.com/joomla/index.php/free/58-convert-ip-address-to-number

Comment: Yep, that's better :) Remember to consider IPv6.

Comment: @Ryan: Yep, that's why I'm explicit about v4 in my answer :-)  IPv6 is 128 bits, details here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#Larger_address_space

Answer (score 3):

Here's simple implementation that outputs what you asked for:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String start = "192.168.0.2";
    String end = "192.168.0.254";

    String[] startParts = start.split("(?<=\\.)(?!.*\\.)");
    String[] endParts = end.split("(?<=\\.)(?!.*\\.)");

    int first = Integer.parseInt(startParts[1]);
    int last = Integer.parseInt(endParts[1]);

    for (int i = first; i <= last; i++) {
        System.out.println(startParts[0] + i);
    }
}
```

Note that this will *only* work for ranges involving the *last* part of the IP address.

Comment: Can you explain the regex `"(?<=\\.)(?!.*\\.)"`?

Comment: @Labeo `"(?<=\\.)"` is a look-behind that asserts the preceding input char is a dot. `"(?!.*\\.)"` is a negative look ahead that asserts the following input does not match any number of characters then a dot. `"(?<=\\.)(?!.*\\.)"` all together means "match just after a dot (between chars) when the rest of the input does *not* contain a dot", which in normal speech is "just after the last dot".

Answer (score 2):

Start at 2, count to 254, and put a "192.168.0." in front of it:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= 254; i++) {
    System.out.println("192.168.0." + i);
}
```

Comment: That's not very generic. OP doesn't specify that only the lower component will need to be incremented, either...

Comment: @Ryan: Works for his specific example, but what if the range exceeded 1 byte?

Comment: @jswolf19: Actually OP just amended the question to specify that in fact only the low byte need be incremented :-), but I agree this answer is not very generic.

Comment: @Ryan: It works for this example but if I have a different netmask I have to handle it differently.

Comment: That approach is too complicated. It's much more easier just to write down 253 strings manually. Or hire someone to make it.

Answer (score 1):

```
void main(String args[]) 
{
String start = "192.168.0.2";
String end = "192.168.0.254";

String[] startParts = start.split("(?<=\\.)(?!.*\\.)");
String[] endParts = end.split("(?<=\\.)(?!.*\\.)");

int first = Integer.parseInt(startParts[1]);
int last = Integer.parseInt(endParts[1]);

for (int i = first; i <= last; i++) 
{
System.out.println(startParts[0] + i);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With [The IPAddress Java library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) you can use code that works with both IPv4 and IPv6 transparently.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager of the IPAddress library.

Here is sample code:

```java
String start = "192.168.0.2", end = "192.168.0.254";
iterate(start, end);
System.out.println();
start = "::1";
end = "::100";
iterate(start, end);

static void iterate(String lowerStr, String upperStr) throws AddressStringException  {
   IPAddress lower = new IPAddressString(lowerStr).toAddress();
   IPAddress upper = new IPAddressString(upperStr).toAddress();
   IPAddressSeqRange range = lower.toSequentialRange(upper);
   for(IPAddress addr : range.getIterable()) {
       System.out.println(addr);
   }
}
```

Output:

```
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
192.168.0.4
...
192.168.0.254

::1
::2
::3
...
::100
```