# Given 2 IP addresses, how do I get all possible IP addresses?

Tags: c#

I have the same problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7303720/2119562) question, however my language is C# (so no toHexString method). So, my problem was that I have these two IPs:

```
String start = "192.168.0.2"
String end = "192.168.0.254"
```

And I want to end up with a list containing:

```
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
192.168.0.4
192.168.0.5
...
192.168.0.254
```

My first solution was looping through all possible IP's per byte. So

```
   var startIpArray = start.Split('.');
   var endIpArray = end.Split('.');
   if (startIpArray [3] != endIpArray[3])
        {
            for (var i = startIpArray [3]; i < endIpArray[3] ; i++)
            {
                listOfIps.Add($"{startIpArray[0]}.{startIpArray[1]}.{startIpArray[2]}.{i}");
            }
        }
```

And repeat that for every group, with more and more for loops per number. My solution is horrible. Is there a better way? The ranges I have are never big enough to cause me to run out of memory making giant lists, so don't worry about that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172677/c-enumerate-ip-addresses-in-a-range/4172699#4172699

Comment: Solved it for me, thanks @viveknuna!

Answer (score 1):

using the [`IPAddressRange`](https://github.com/jsakamoto/ipaddressrange) library, you can enumerate your IPs like that:

```
var start = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.2");
var end = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.254");

var range = new IPAddressRange(start, end);

foreach (var ip in range)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ip);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would rather not use an external library.

Comment: @ohyeah ok. then you can checkout the answers on the question vivek nuna linked.