# Get all possible IPs between 2 given addresses

Tags: c#, .net-core, ip, ip-address

I was following the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40303177/given-2-ip-addresses-how-do-i-get-all-possible-ip-addresses), but using the code in the answer doesn't work the way I would like.

I would like to have some sort of method for getting all possible IPs between two given IPs (as the question said) and store them in an array or some kind of object, but the OP there didn't try to use the library suggested, as was commented.

I am using .NET Core 3.1.

**Main**:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length < 4)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Not enough args!");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Sufficient arguments.");

    IPAddress ipRangeStart = IPAddress.Parse(args[0]);
    IPAddress ipRangeEnd = IPAddress.Parse(args[1]);
    Console.WriteLine("IPs parsed.");
    int port;
    try
    {
        port = Convert.ToInt32(args[2]);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw new FormatException("Invalid port value!");
    }

    if (port > 65535 || port < 1) throw new InvalidOperationException("Port must be in the valid range!");
            
    Console.WriteLine("Port integer parsed.");

    string filePath = args[3];

    if (!(File.Exists(filePath))) File.Create(filePath);
            
    Console.WriteLine("Output file resolved.");

    IPAddressRange addies = new IPAddressRange(ipRangeStart, ipRangeEnd);

    Console.WriteLine("IP range created.");

    List<IPAddy> ipList = new List<IPAddy>();
            
    Console.WriteLine("IP list initialized.");
            
    Console.WriteLine("Adding IPs to list...");
            
    // Program hangs here
    
    foreach (var ip in addies)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parsing: " + ip.ToString());
        ipList.Add(new IPAddy(ip.ToString()));    
    }
            
    Console.WriteLine("IP range parsed.");
            
    Console.WriteLine("Scanning...");
    Dictionary<string, bool > ipsEvaluated = Scanner.ScanRanges(ipList.ToArray(), port);

    Console.WriteLine("Evaluating keys...");
    string[] IPPortsOpen = ipsEvaluated.getTrueKeys();
            
    Console.WriteLine("Writing results...");
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(filePath, true);

    foreach (string i in IPPortsOpen)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(i);
    }
            
    Console.WriteLine("Done!");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this IPv4? or IPv6? If we assume IPv4... then IP addresses are really just 32-bit big-endian unsigned integers. Let's take, as examples, 125.80.207.121 and 141.221.132.118; now think of them in terms of hex...

decimal 125.80.207.121 is hex 7D.50.CF.79; 7D50CF79 is 2102447993

decimal 141.221.132.118 is hex 8D.DD.84.4F; 8DDD844F is 2380104783

So the IP addresses between 125.80.207.121 and 141.221.132.118 are the same as the *integers* between 2102447993 and 2380104783, when considered as 32-bit big-endian unsigned values - then just split the octets into pieces and output each octet as an integer.

Comment: @ryzenup yes - or rather the runtime does; at the language level, it doesn't *need* them - values are values are values - there is no concept of a "hex integer", or even a "decimal integer" - just an integer. But what you're looking for may be `someHex = someInteger.ToString("x2")` and `someInteger = Convert.ToInt32(someHex, 16)`

Comment: @ryzenup although you might prefer to use `uint` (aka `UInt32`) here: `var val = Convert.ToUInt32("7D50CF79", 16); // 2102447993`

Comment: what do I store the IP as?

Comment: @ryzenup `"x2"` is a format specifier that means "hexadecimal" (give or take); the `16` in our `Convert` call is the `fromBase` parameter - we are parsing from base-16 (aka hexadecimal)

Comment: @ryzenup "what do I store the IP as" - you tell me; what do you *want* to store them as? if you're trying to iterate over IPv4 addresses in a range, then `uint` is the most obvious choice

Comment: having multiple decimals in a non-string value doesn't really work...

Comment: @ryzenup it does if you're thinking about them as octets; but: just for a moment, let's say that you can parse 125.80.207.121 into 4 integers `int a=125, b=80, c=207, d=121;` now consider `uint ip = (uint)(a << 24 | b << 16 | c << 8 | d);` - this has the value 2102447993. Do you see what we're doing here? we're combining 4 octets into a single value using bit-shifting to arrange the octets in a big-endian layout. Which is exactly what IPv4 is, fundamentally.

Comment: that is actually what my `IPAddy` class does. Now all I must do is write a cast

Comment: I apologize, at the moment I did not understand what the answer OP was on about with hex numbers. This COMPLETELY makes sense to me now.