# JSch send command to multiple ip

Tags: java, android, ssh, ip, jsch

i want to send one command to multiple ip addresses with jsch android, for example i have range of ip from 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.0.254 and i want to send one command to all this ip's, is it possible?

my code now

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String host;
    String user;
    String password;

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    }


    // my command
    public void test(){
        EditText t1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user);
        EditText t2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.host);
        EditText t3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        if (t1 != null && t2 != null && t3 != null) {
            host = t2.getText().toString();
            user = t1.getText().toString();
            password = t3.getText().toString();

            int port=22;
            try{

                JSch jsch = new JSch();
                Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
                session.setPassword(password);
                session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                session.setTimeout(10000);
                session.connect();
                ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");
                channel.setCommand("my command");
                channel.connect();
                channel.disconnect();

            }
            catch(JSchException e){
            }
        }
    }

}
```

i want like this, so when i click to send button it's sending command "reboot" to 192.168.0.1,192.168.0.2,192.168.0.3 until 192.168.0.254. i think you understand me and sorry for my english.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr3Mp.png)

Comment: And the problem is? Just loop your code for each IP.

Comment: how can you imagine 254 ip addresses in one page? :)

Comment: What “page”? I do not understand your comment.

Comment: wait, maybe i didn't understand you too...loop? what you mean? can you explain?

Comment: I mean `for` loop.

Comment: can you show small example?

Comment: OK, I see, you need to "calculate" the IPs in the range. Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/q/7303720/850848?